# What is the minimum speed that the car must travel at to avoid hearing the noise?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, drag, viscosity

An aluminum sphere has been tied to the rear bumper of a 2005 Toyota corolla by a nylon string. When the car moves the sphere bounces on the road and makes a loud noise. What is the minimum speed that the car must travel at to avoid hearing the noise? the sphere weighs 100g and has a diameter of 100 cm. The string is 175 cm long, weighs 5g and is attached to the bumper 45 cm above the ground. The viscosity of air is 1.825x10^-5 kg/m-s. Wind speed is negligible.

So, I'm pretty stumped on the problem. Im assuming that, in order for the sphere not to make a sound, it must be suspended in the air. However, the radius of the sphere is larger than the height of the bumper. Also it doesn't mention anything about spinning, so how could you calculate the lift as it relates to the gravitational force. For my free body diagram I had tension at an angle to the bumper with a drag force in the opposite direction. Vertically, there's the gravitational down, but I'm not positive what would oppose that.

Comment: I assume the answer is not supposed to be "above the speed of sound"?

Comment: I thought about that too, but it's not logical for a car to move that fast.

Comment: Not logical maybe, but possible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThrustSSC

Comment: @LucasGoodin it's not illogical and there have been cars that moved faster than sound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThrustSSC. But, the real problem is that the question is about the ball flying, not about not hearing the sound.

Comment: I don't think the "supersonic" car is the expected answer. First it would make all other parameters irrelevant, and even for supersonic speeds, sound would still propagate through the cable. Secondly, a $100\,\mathrm{cm}$ aluminum ball (weighting $100\,\mathrm{g}$!) sounds quite unrealistic to me. I suspect a typo in the question. Are you sure that the diameter is $100\,\mathrm{cm}$ ? I've found similar phrasings of the problem online with much more reasonable diameter (such as $D = 7 \,\mathrm{cm}$).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it clear whether you are really trying to out-run the sound the ball makes on the ground or just trying to get/maintain lift-off.  Acceleration and drag affect the force applied by the line between the car and the ball, and that must be high enough to overcome gravity at whatever angle the line has from horizontal, in order to get lift-off.  I would add that drag on the line and the sphere are affected by the the airflow around the vehicle.

Comment: If it's a potential trick question, 0 m/s is also a potential minimum speed for the car to hear no sound.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following picture for notations/geometry of the problem:

[image: Geometry of the problem]

What happens physically is that in the reference frame of the car moving at $U$, the wind is moving at $-U$. It thus exerts a drag on the sphere (the lift is zero because of the up-down symmetry of the sphere). This drag is compensated by the cable tension in the $x$ direction. However, because the cable forms an angle $\theta$ WRT the horizontal direction, it also exerts a force in the vertical direction, compensating the weight of the aluminum ball.

### Equations:

Let's call $\overrightarrow{f} = - f \overrightarrow{e_x}$ the drag force exerted by the wind on the ball. For large Reynolds number, we have $f = \frac{1}{2} \rho_{\mathrm{air}} C_d U^2 (D^2\pi/4)$, where $\rho_{\mathrm{air}}$ is the density of air, $C_d$ is the [drag coefficient for a smooth ball](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0231.shtml) ($C_d \approx 0.4$ for $1000 < \mathrm{Re} < 300000$), and $D$ the diameter of the ball.

Equilibrium condition in the $x$ direction: $T \cos(\theta) = f$, where $T$ is the cable tension. Equilibrium condition in the vertical direction: $M g = T \sin(\theta)$, with $M$ the mass of the ball (if the mass of the cable is negligible as it is here), so the two combined give: $f \tan(\theta) = Mg$.

Finally, if you denote $h$ the height at which the cable is attached to the bumper, and $H(U)$ the height of the center of the ball, you have that $\sin(\theta) = \frac{h-H(u)}{L}$, with $L$ the length of the cable.

The minimum speed needed for the ball to "float" is such that $H(U) = D/2$, so putting everything together:

$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{h - D/2}{L}$$

$$U^2 = \frac{8 M g}{\rho_{\mathrm{air}}C_d\pi D^2} \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} = \frac{8 M g}{\rho_{\mathrm{air}}C_d\pi D^2} \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{8 M g}{\rho_{\mathrm{air}}C_d\pi D^2} \frac{\sqrt{L^2-(h-D/2)^2}}{h-D/2}$$

Of course, because $\theta > 0$ (the ball cannot go higher than the bumper otherwise the weight and the tension would both be pointing downwards), all of this only makes sense if $D/2 < h$, i.e if the ball does not touch the ground when the cable is horizontal. Because a $100\,\mathrm{cm}$, $100\,\mathrm{g}$ aluminum ball looks very suspicious to me (I would guess it would be much heavier), I assume that there is an issue in the statement of the problem and the ball is actually *$10$ cm* large. Replacing all variables, I find $U \approx 45\,\mathrm{m/s} $ (please check by yourself). The last step is to check that we are indeed in the range for which $C_d \approx 0.4$. The diametral Reynold numbers is $\frac{U D}{\nu}$, with $\nu \approx 1.5 \times 10^{-5}\, \mathrm{m^2/s}$ for air, so that $\mathrm{Re} \approx 300000$. We are just at the edge of the validity regime for $C_d$ (just below the drag crisis). Redoing the calculation for a $C_d \approx 0.1-0.2$ (past the drag crisis), would give a $U$ of respectively $90\,\mathrm{m/s}$ and $65\,\mathrm{m/s}$, which would be difficult to achieve with a regular car...

So according to this model, and assuming I did not make a mistake in my calculations, you can answer the question *How fast would the car need to go for you not to hear the sound?* Quite fast... (at least $165\,\mathrm{km/h}$ or $100\,\mathrm{mph}$ in the most favorable case).

Comment: Check the radius pf the sphere and the height of the attachment point on the car...

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to answer "faster than the speed of sound" to a problem with this many parameters, unless this is a "trap" question... Moreover, as adressed in another answer, even if you went faster than sound (in air), sound could still propagate through the cable. I adressed the issue of the diameter in my answer. A $100\,\mathrm{cm}$ aluminum sphere is very suspicious IMHO, that is why I suspect that there is a typo and the actual diameter is $10\,\mathrm{cm}$ instead.

Comment: Plus you find similar phrasings of the problem online, with much more reasonable dimensions for the aluminum sphere (for instance, $D=7\,\mathrm{cm}$ here : https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/aluminum-sphere-tied-rear-bumper-2005-toyota-corolla-nylon-string-car-moves-sphere-bounces-q44421940 )

Answer (score -1):

since the noise also travels thru the attached line and you travel with the "sound machine " you will never escape, think of a loudspeaker  in your back will you ever escape the sound , this question is just a joke! al the exakt things in it make ist less likely  to see the simple solution.

Comment: this is true that you cannot "escape" the sound that way. However, at sufficiently large velocities the sphere should be floating due to the drag and the tension of the cable... thus removing the sound

Comment: The question title is misleading. It's about a floating ball. But, even assuming the problem was was that you are trailing a noise source, the fact that the noise source is outside the car means that you can escape the noise (ignoring transmission up the cable, which I know you brought up) if you travel fast enough. The speakers are inside the car in a body of air being carried with the car. So, the situation is different.

Comment: Admittedly, while the OP phrases it this way, I do wonder whether the original poser of the problem to the OP meant it as a joke.